# Placeholder is not getting added in select box

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code on refresh :

```
 $('#vnfMobilityParamSelect').change(function() {
    }).multipleSelect({
        width: '100%',
        selectAll: false,
        minimumCountSelectedType: 4

    });
```

This is the html part :

```
<select id="vnfMobilityParamSelect" name="vnfMobilityParamSelect" float="right" multiple="multiple" style="min-width:100%;"> </select>
```

Inside a function I am trying to add placeholder, on satisfying a condition :

```
  if(selectedVNF=='SGW')
    {
        $("#vnfMobilityParamSelect").prop('placeholder','Select Tracking Area');  
    }
  else
  {
       $("#vnfMobilityParamSelect").prop('placeholder','Select Pool Area');
  }
```

But it appears blank only, i.e. no placeholder is added. I have tried the same using attr, document.getElementById, nothing works. Please help!

Comment: Native DOM `select` element doesn't support `placeholder` attribute. Probably this is option of plugin

Comment: Since you're adding the placeholder after the JS has initialized. You probably need to re-initialize the select box on the front end. Check the docs of your plugin to see if there's a re-init method. Or perhaps destroy, then init.

Comment: Ya But Multi-select drop down Plugin Supports Placeholder through Script

Comment: I have put an option field. Left the rest intact. Did : <option selected="selected">Select</option> Doesn't work

Comment: <select><option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="hurr">INDIA</option>
</select> Just Use Once

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#vnfMobilityParamSelect').change(function() {
}).multipleSelect({
    width: '100%',
    selectAll: false,
    placeholder:"Your Text",
    minimumCountSelectedType: 4

});
```

Comment: I did this before. But then Your Text is retained. I want to change it depending on a choice, there is also an else part where the value of placeholder changes to : 'Select Pool Area'

Comment: @PrasitaMukherjee Try `$('#vnfMobilityParamSelect').multipleSelect('placeholder', 'Select Pool Area');`. Now would be easier to help if you privde relevant plugin link and check DOC if this plugin support dynamic option change. Otherwise, destroy it and reinitialize it

Comment: Error : unkown method placeholder by doing this

Comment: @PrasitaMukherjee Why don't you check plugin DOC??? Be aware, we have **still** no idea which plugin you are using BECAUSE you still didn't provide relevant link pointing to this plugin...